# Validar la exitencia de un token en localStorage del navegador

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, vue.js, vuex

la cuestión que tengo un token guardado en el localstorage y lo que quiero es que si se borra ese token del navegador me redirija automáticamente a la ventana de login si la necesidad de que refresque la ventana o algo mas, imagines que hice un borrado manual de ese token entonces inmediatamente me lleve a la ventana de login. Estoy usando Node.js, vue y vuex, estuve leyendo que el localstorage no es reactivo a cambio pero no entendi mucho lo que decía.

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes utilizar computed properties

```
Vue({
 computed: {
   token() {
    return storage.get('TOKEN_KEY');
   }
 }
});
```

Y con espo podrías hacerlo "reactivo", puedes consultar la siguiente liga para más información: [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Si lo que necesitas que sea en toda tu aplicación, puedes utilizar [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) para registrar el comportamiento en todos los componentes de tu aplicación.

```
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    token() {
     return storage.get('TOKEN_KEY');
    } 
  } 
})
```

Y para hacer lo que necesitas entonces habría que agregar watchers.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
  props: ['user'],
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { header: 'Today' },
        { avatar: 'https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/lists/1.jpg', title: 'Brunch this weekend?', subtitle: "<span class='text--primary'>Ali Connors</span> &mdash; I'll be in your neighborhood doing errands this weekend. Do you want to hang out?" },
        { divider: true, inset: true },
        { avatar: 'https://vuetifyjs.com/static/doc-images/lists/2.jpg', title: 'Summer BBQ <span class="grey--text text--lighten-1">4</span>', subtitle: "<span class='text--primary'>to Alex, Scott, Jennifer</span> &mdash; Wish I could come, but I'm out of town this weekend." },
      ],
      vertoken: '',
    };
  },
  watch() {
    // this.vertoken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    // this.debouncedGetrouter();
    this.verificartoken();
  },
  created() {
    this.verificartoken();
  },
  methods: {
    verificartoken() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken') === undefined || localStorage.getItem('accessToken') === null) {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Login', params: { successAlert: true } });
      }
    },
    token() {
      return localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    },
    token2() {
      if (!this.token()) {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Login', params: { successAlert: true } });
      }
    },
  },
  components: {
    payroll: PayRoll,
    Expenses,
    Incomes,
    UserChart,
  },
};
</script>
```

Asi es como tengo mi codigo pero no hay reacion cuando borro la variable maualmente del localstorage.